Kafka enable.idempotence and Transaction API
Does Kafka require enabling idempotence for the producer running in a transaction?
putting in another way, does the transaction API comes with idempotency out of band or an explicit enabling is required?
Based of my understanding, transactions don't need no idempotence as it's either committed or aborted, this way when the consumer resumes there is no message loss and starts reprocessing with the true offset, no idempotency here means no retrying is made by aborted transactions which potentially cause duplicates.
Is my understanding correct?

For anyone who looks for an answer to that, every transactional producer is also an idempotent producer.
